# getter setter in inner private class in java

Tags: java, getter-setter

I want to create bean in java corresponding to below json

```
{
    "name": "",
    "id": "",
    "dept": {
        "deptId": "",
        "deptName": "",
        "course": {
            "courseId": "",
        }
    }
}
```

My idea is to create parent class and keep `dept` and `course` as inner private classes and then have getters setters to get or set data and form parent bean. But I am getting error "Change visibility to the public"

How can I access private fields of inner private class to get and set data?

Comment: what is your code?

Comment: what is you **Java** code?

Answer (score 2):

try this way its will work

```
public class firstClass{

    private String name;
    private String id;
    Department dept;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public Department getDept() {
        return dept;
    }
    public void setDept(Department dept) {
        this.dept = dept;
    }


}

class Department{
    private int departId;
    private String deptName;
    Course course;
    public int getDepartId() {
        return departId;
    }
    public void setDepartId(int departId) {
        this.departId = departId;
    }
    public String getDeptName() {
        return deptName;
    }
    public void setDeptName(String deptName) {
        this.deptName = deptName;
    }
    public Course getCourse() {
        return course;
    }
    public void setCourse(Course course) {
        this.course = course;
    }

}


class Course{
    private int courseId;

    public int getCourseId() {
        return courseId;
    }

    public void setCourseId(int courseId) {
        this.courseId = courseId;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access private fields. Why don't you create a getter and setter for the inner class private fields?

And, maybe you should consider using [gson](https://github.com/google/gson) library.

Answer (score 0):

You at least have to make say nested public *interfaces*, say Dept and Course, with your private (static) nested private classes DeptImpl and SourceImpl.

```
public class X {
    public interface Dept { ... }
    private static class DeptImpl extends Dept { ... }
    public Dept getDept() { ... }

    public Dept createDept(...) {
        DeptImpl dept = new DeptImpl(...); ...
        return dept;
    }
```

Maybe you need to provide a factory method createDept.

In some cases the implementing class can be anonymous `new Dept() { ... }`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Builder Design pattern with immutable Objects:

```
public class Class {

private final String name;
private final int id;
private final Department dept;

private Class(ClassBuilder classBuilder){
    this.name = classBuilder.getName();
    this.id = classBuilder.getId();
    this.dept = classBuilder.getDept();
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public Department getDept() {
    return dept;
}

private static class Department{

    private final int deptId;
    private final String deptName;
    private final Course course;

    private Department(DepartmentBuilder departmentBuilder){
        this.deptId = departmentBuilder.getDeptId();
        this.deptName = departmentBuilder.getDeptName();
        this.course = departmentBuilder.getCourse();
    }

    public int getDeptId() {
        return deptId;
    }

    public String getDeptName() {
        return deptName;
    }

    public Course getCourse() {
        return course;
    }

    private static class Course{

        private final int courseId;

        private Course(CourseBuilder courseBuilder){
            this.courseId = courseBuilder.getCourseId();
        }

        public int getCourseId() {
            return courseId;
        }
    }
}

public static class ClassBuilder{

    private final String name;
    private final int id;
    private final Department dept;

    public ClassBuilder(String name, int id, Department dept){
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
        this.dept = dept;
    }

    public Department getDept() {
        return dept;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Class build(){
        return new Class(this);
    }
}

public static class DepartmentBuilder {

    private final int deptId;
    private final String deptName;
    private final Department.Course course;

    public DepartmentBuilder(int deptId, String deptName, Department.Course course ){
        this.deptId = deptId;
        this.deptName = deptName;
        this.course = course;
    }

    public int getDeptId() {
        return deptId;
    }

    public String getDeptName() {
        return deptName;
    }

    public Department.Course getCourse() {
        return course;
    }

    public Department build(){
        return new Department(this);
    }
}

public static class CourseBuilder{

    private final int courseId ;

    public CourseBuilder(int courseId){
        this.courseId = courseId;
    }

    public int getCourseId() {
        return courseId;
    }

    public Department.Course build(){
        return new Department.Course(this);
    }
}
```

}

```
public class Sample {

public static void main(String ... strings){

    Class clazz = new Class.ClassBuilder("ClassName", 1, new Class.DepartmentBuilder(1, "departmentName", new Class.CourseBuilder(2).build()).build()).build();

    System.out.println(clazz.getDept());
}
```

}